# Почему возникает такая ошибка и как "правильно" написать деструктор?

Tags: c++, классы

Проблема возникает именно в том момент когда вызывается десктруктор, если доверит создание деструктора "автоматике", то ни чего не меняется и все равно выпадает такая ошибка. Собственно у меня возникает два вопроса:

1. Принципы написания деструктора класса (можно ссылочку, только на русском желательно)
2. Что здесь и как надо исправить/дописать что бы все работала правильно и ни каких ошибок не возникало ?

[Test.cpp](https://pastebin.com/Zt4xrccc)

[A.h](https://pastebin.com/F6LVKHwy)

[A.cpp](https://pastebin.com/F3Xq9Aus)

[image: Ошибка]

Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Вместо указания ссылок приведите минимальную компилируемую программу, которая воспроизводит проблему.

Comment: Сейчас попробую сократить.

Comment: Так, а теперь я вообще в панике. Я собрал все в один файл, ни чего не меняя и оно заработало. Кажется тут было дело не в коде, а visual studio, он перед компиляцией скачал какие то файлы (или взял их от куда-то) и все нормально скомпилировалось и выполнилось, без ошибок. Простите, что скидываю еще одну ссылку [test2.cpp](https://pastebin.com/35bcgJrr) По факту я создал новый проект и закинул все в один файл и все заработало

Comment: Открыл старый проект, который до этого был и о чудо он заработал, похоже visual studio все таки дурила, а потом скачала нужные файлы (я хз что она там скачала, слишком быстро) и все заработало.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас классическая ошибка: нет копирующего конструктора, он генерируется компилятором, и просто копирует почленно - в том числе `a`.

В итоге:

```
A test3 = test1 + test2;
```

Создается временный объект с выделением памяти. Далее этот временный объект передается конструктору `test3`, и *указатель* на выделенную временному объекту память просто копируется. Затем временный объект уничтожается, память освобождается. Затем, когда уничтожается `test3`, *эта же память* освобождается второй раз.

Учтите, в программировании действует *презумпция корректности компилятора*. Пояснение "а, проблема в компиляторе" выдает новичка с головой. Опытный программист будет до последнего искать ошибку у себя...

Правильное решение -

```
A(const A& nw):n(10),a(new int[n]) {
    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) a[i] = nw.a[i];
}
```

Полуправильное :) -

```
A test3;
test3 = test1 + test 2;
```

И еще - не стесняйтесь ставить `const` - например, аргумент оператора присваивания вы же не меняете - делайте его константным. Функция вывода объект не меняет? делайте ее константной...

P.S. И еще - не нужно задавать вопрос с картинкой, из которой достаточно одной строки, зато лучше давайте код прямо в вопросе... Будь настроение не таким благодушным - не полез бы открывать еще три окна, чтоб на ваш код посмотреть... Зацепило только ваше "компилятор виноват" - ну не верю, чтоб он был виноват в такой ерунде :) - нарваться на ошибку компилятора в таком месте - все равно что подорваться на какой-нибудь мине времен Наполеона на Красной площади :)

Comment: Спасибо, за объяснение. Очень нужная информация, которая не везде есть.